# Tessellate a plane of points

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I have a file filled with 3d points. The points form a plane. Here is an example file:

```
25
1 -1 0
1 -0.5 0
1 0 0
1 0.5 0
1 1 0
0.5 -1 0
0.5 -0.5 0
0.5 0 0
0.5 0.5 0
0.5 1 0
0 -1 0
0 -0.5 0
0 0 0
0 0.5 0
0 1 0
-0.5 -1 0
-0.5 -0.5 0
-0.5 0 0
-0.5 0.5 0
-0.5 1 0
-1 -1 0
-1 -0.5 0
-1 0 0
-1 0.5 0
-1 1 0
```

Edit: Since my example set of points was too simple, here is a more complex example.

```
30
-0.298858 -0.816497 1.11536
0.0546949 -0.816497 0.761802
0.408248 -0.816497 0.408248
0.761802 -0.816497 0.0546949
1.11536 -0.816497 -0.298858
-0.462158 -0.489898 0.952056
-0.108604 -0.489898 0.598502
0.244949 -0.489898 0.244949
0.598502 -0.489898 -0.108604
0.952056 -0.489898 -0.462158
-0.625457 -0.163299 0.788756
-0.271904 -0.163299 0.435203
0.0816497 -0.163299 0.0816497
0.435203 -0.163299 -0.271904
0.788756 -0.163299 -0.625457
-0.788756 0.163299 0.625457
-0.435203 0.163299 0.271904
-0.0816497 0.163299 -0.0816497
0.271904 0.163299 -0.435203
0.625457 0.163299 -0.788756
-0.952056 0.489898 0.462158
-0.598502 0.489898 0.108604
-0.244949 0.489898 -0.244949
0.108604 0.489898 -0.598502
0.462158 0.489898 -0.952056
-1.11536 0.816497 0.298858
-0.761802 0.816497 -0.0546949
-0.408248 0.816497 -0.408248
-0.0546949 0.816497 -0.761802
0.298858 0.816497 -1.11536
```

These points are plotted like so:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/6zRrA.png]

This file states that there are 25 points in the plane, and lists the points. The points are regularly spaced. Based on this information, how could I form triangles out of the point data and store it in a `std::vector<Tri>` where `Tri` is a

```
struct Tri 
{
  double x1, y1, z1;
  double x2, y2, z2;
  double x3, y3, z3;
};
```

Note also: Problem restrictions: External libraries are not allowed. The use of C++0X is not allowed (compiler: g++ 4.5.2).

Comment: Do you want the points to be vertices of the triangles, or do you want the triangles to surround the points? Can the triangles intersect? Do they have to somehow cover the convex hull of the points?

Comment: The points should be the vertexes. The triangles should never intersect. If they do, the point data is malformed.

Comment: Why your triangle contains only 3 double numbers? usually a triangle is defined by 3 **points**

Comment: @PermanentGuest I fixed that, excuse my error.

Comment: Your file has structure and it would be easy to exploit the ordering for THIS example. Are you wanting solutions for a more general case of unordered/unstructured points in the file?

Comment: No, the points are always structured, unless someone messes with the file, then the data is invalid. That is not a concern however.

Comment: So is it the algorithm you need or the file reading functionality? Or both?

Comment: @mathematician1975 I need the algorithm to tessellate the points. Reading the points is trivial.

Comment: An important piece of information is whether a) strips and fans are supported, and b) whether there exists a vertex cache (such as in virtually all modern graphics hardware). Both can have considerable effects on performance, and will/may need different vertex ordering. Also, is there a form of culling going on (important for winding!) or not? One should be clear about all these before talking about code.

Comment: @Damon I'm not quite following you...

Comment: @Drise: There are 2 ways one can draw a triangle from 3 vertices, clockwise or counter-clockwise. This is often used to do backface culling, in that case they all need to have the same winding. Also, one can have "just triangles" and "triangle strips" and "triangle fans". The latter two use fewer vertices per triangle. Lastly, for performance reasons, many graphics pipelines (and current hardware) cache the last few seen vertices after transform. Which means that the order in which triangles are submitted is not trivial if performance matters. Those are things one should know before starting.

Comment: @Damon I'm not trying to draw them. I'm just trying to associate a set of 3 3D points and call it a triangle.

Comment: Just so I can get a feel for what you are doing, if I have a square, using your system, could I make two triangles with it at the same time?  Say, if the corners are numbers 1234 clockwise, would you accept the triangles formed by 123 and 143 as being non-intersecting?  Because otherwise, I don;t think the problem is necessarily solvable.

Comment: @bigbenbt Your statement *"the corners are numbers 1234 clockwise, would you accept the triangles formed by 123 and 143 as being non-intersecting"* is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

read the first line, call it `N`.  Read the rest of the points into an array `A`.

```
Point xdir = A[1] - A[0];
int xdim = 2;
while (A[xdim] - A[xdim-1] == xdir) xdim++;
int ydim = N / xdim;
for (int y = 0; y < ydim-1; y++) {
   for (int x = 0; x < xdim-1; x++) {
      addTriangle(A[y*xdim+x],A[(y+1)*xdim+x],A[(y+1)*xdim+(x+1)]);
      addTriangle(A[y*xdim+x],A[y*xdim+(x+1)],A[(y+1)*xdim+(x+1)]);
   }
}
```

Of course, this assumes you're really getting all of your points in grid order.  If not, sort them first.

Comment: Can you explain with more detail? What is N? What is N2? Why the square root?

Comment: Because your points are in a grid.  Given a K point square grid, the side dimension is sqrt(K).  Or might your grid not be square like the example?

Comment: I'm assuming `N2` is the first line's value which is the number of points in the grid, i.e., `25`.  Then you want to take the square-root of `25` in order to get a 5x5 grid.

Comment: I gave an example of a square out of habit and simplicity, but in fact it can be a rectangle.

Comment: Then you need to detect the dimensions of the rectangle first.  `X=1+max(i) such that A[0].x == A[i].x` and `Y=N2/X` or some such.

Comment: I think you are assuming the plane that the points lie in. If I'm wrong, please correct me.

Comment: @Drise: for that last comment, yes.  Otherwise, no.  To fix the last comment, just look for when the vector A[i+1]-A[i] changes.

Comment: @KeithRandall Could you correct your answer to include all the of the comments and such?

Answer (score 0):

Separate the grid on the plane into a set of lines. The tesselation is given by taking each pair of adjacent points on a line and adding the closest point of each member of the pair in the adjacent lines to the pair.

You can separate the plane into lines by using vector arithmetics. Take the first point in the file as the plane basis, and the vector to the second point as your X axis. Project the vector from the first point to any point on the X axis vector, and use the length of the projection as the X coordinates. Since you assume a regular grid, these values should be 0, 1, 2, 3, and so on, straightforwardly segmenting the points into lines.

Answer (score 0):

For the tesselation algorithm, try creating, and pushing to the vector, right triangles of adjacent points (without overlapping them). Assuming you have stored all points in an `m x n` matrix in the right order, you can create this set of triangles:

- `{(i,j),(i+1,j),(i+1,j+1)}` for `0 < i < m-1` and `0 < j < n-1`.
- `{(i,j+1), (i+1,j+1), (i,j)` for `0 < i < m-1` and `0 < j < n-1`.

I used the form {p1,p2,p3} for a triangle and (x,y) for the point's index pair in the matrix. In your case also, these **m** and **n** variables are equal to 5.

Answer (score 0):

There are of course many different ways to get a set of triangles from a set of vertices, so I'm not sure I understand the entire problem requirements.

But my approach would probably look something like this:

1. To account for floating point rounding and/or data accuracy issues, I would first determine a normal vector to the plane, using something like a least squares fit algorithm.  (Though you don't need the plane itself, just the direction.)
2. Write algorithms to use that normal vector to determine some common plane questions like "Is point D in the interior of triangle ABC?" and "Do segments AB and CD intersect?" (in the plane projection).

If you have some known structure to the input that makes it easy from this point, or an existing plane algorithm you want to use, great.

If you just want to get any set of non-overlapping triangles that tesselate the convex hull:

1. Start with any three points and a single triangle.  Remember also an ordered cycle of vertices forming the boundary polygon of the region covered so far.  Then add the rest of the points one at a time.
2. If the new point to add is in the interior of an existing triangle, replace that triangle with three subtriangles.
3. Otherwise, determine which N (N>=2) line segments from boundary polygon vertices to the new point do not intersect the boundary polygon.  Add (N-1) new triangles.  The new point replaces (N-2) old points as a new vertex in the boundary polygon.
4. Assuming it's a good thing to avoid nearly-collinear triangles and unnecessarily long segments: Loop over the triangle edges which are not on the boundary, and check whether the  quadrilateral covered by the two adjacent triangles is convex, and whether its other diagonal is (significantly) shorter than the common triangle edge being investigated. If so, replace those two triangles. Repeat until no more such substitutions can be made. (This loop must terminate since the total length of edges is always decreasing, and there are a finite number of tesselations.)